# The ways to transform a source xml to another xml

Tags: xml, transform

There's a source xml document. Now i want to transform it to another xml document with same content but different elements order. The thinking up to my mind is using xslt and i think this way is fine too.

However, i wanna to know are there some other ways to do so ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

*xslt* is good, but you could also call some XML library from a scripting language, or even write your program in C or C++ ....

It really depends of performance considerations.... (If you have to process hundreds of gigabyte sized XML documents daily, or only a few dozen of megabytes documents once).

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it depends on performance considerations. Which approaches do you think would be faster, and why? Would you expect the sort engine in an XSLT processor to be faster or slower than the sort library in C++? I would expect it to be much the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a programming language like Perl, Java, PHP, Ruby, Python, etc to parse the XML, then output the new one in the desired form.

But, as you said, XSLT is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to XSLT and using your favorite programming language, there is a command line tool `xmlstarlet` which can do a lot of xml processing with much simpler syntax than xslt. See here for an overview

http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php

and here for a nice tutorial:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-starlet/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Also consider XQuery. My usual rule-of-thumb is that XQuery is better than XSLT for simple tasks, whereas XSLT is better for complex tasks. You haven't shown us your data, but the solution in XQuery might be as simple as

```
<data> {
  for $row in /*/row
  order by $row/sort-key
  return $row
}</data>
```